# How parent directive set different variables from the child directive value with the isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I created a directive for date selector and also I have a search directive which is a form. So the search directive using date selector directive. I have 2 date selector one for departure date and the other for arrival date. My question is how can I set the departureDateTime and arrivalDateTime on search directive from the value selected by date selector directive. At the moment on performing search both of departureDateTime and arrivalDateTime are null. How can I get it to show me the correct selected values?

```
    app.directive('selectDate', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            dateObj: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: 'DateSelector.html',
        controller: function($scope){
          $scope.today = function(dateObj) {
            $scope.dateObj = new Date();
          };
          $scope.today();

          $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.dateObj = null;
          };

          // Disable weekend selection
          $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
            return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
          };

          $scope.toggleMin = function() {
            $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
          };
          $scope.toggleMin();

          $scope.open = function($event) {

            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.opened = true;
          };

          $scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1
          };

          `enter code here`$scope.format = 'dd-MMMM-yyyy';
        },
        controllerAs: 'dateCtrl'
    };
    }]);


  app.directive('searchForm', ['sharedProperties',function(sharedProperties){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'SearchForm.html',
        link: function(scope, element){
            var form = $("#search-form");

        },
        controller: function($scope){

            $scope.departureDateTime= null;
            $scope.arrivalDateTime = null;



            $scope.search = function(){

                console.log($scope.departureDateTime, $scope.arrivalDateTime);

            }

        },
        controllerAs: 'form'
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the "link" function may solve this.
http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/